# Simple Active Record Implementation in .NET 2.0+

Tags: .net, activerecord

I'm looking for a very simple example of active record in .NET (code samples to be honest)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

David Hayden does such a good job explaining it that I wouldn't want to duplicate his work:

- [Domain-Driven Design Using Active Record in .NET](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/06/21/2995.aspx)

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted!  Should have looked this up David's blog first ;)